800Vdc Ethernet power line communication
We wish to use standard Ethernet protocol to communicate 50m on a 800Vdc cable. We need a communication module at each end. How to do this? It needs to be compliant to IEEE 802.3

What is Standard Ethernet Protocol? Ethernet is a bunch of layers. PLC - Power Line Communication - can replace the physical layer, while you keep other layers. What's the question?

By the way, your question is probably going to be removed soon, if you need to talk about it, send me a direct message

I am learning fast here, compliance  to IEEE 802.3

here, have a look. https://nessum.org/media/technology-blog/what-is-power-line-communication

Hi TQQQ, can you please send me a message. I am learning how to use platform. Thanks

Article is fantastic thank you

Apparently, there is no DM on the platform.  Here: https://www.reddit.com/user/lapserdak1/

Lethal voltages over Ethernet? What will they think of next? You had better have good liability insurance.

@James_Bond I put a reddit link above, contact me there

You may be able to adapt IEEE 901 AKA ethernet powerline https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1901 Here is an example schematic:

How do these powerline networking adapters work?
Instead of L and N you could probably connect the capacitors to the 800VDC line and transmit over that. You also need to make sure that the 800VDC line does not have frequency content below 100MHz that can disrupt communications of ethernet powerline, so use a ferrite or line filter on the load if it's noisy (but not between the powerline ethernet points).

Thank you for your support. We are using inverters complying to AS4777.2. Do you recommend performing FFT of line? There are 50hz harmonics, dominate being 9th and 11th. Inverter switches at 20kHz with line filters. Do you see any issues?

Looking at the datasheet with a quick glance  looks like the bandpass to transmit is 2.4MHz to 23MHz so make sure nothing is there.

Also make sure your caps follow proper creepage and clearance requirements for 800VDC.

Fantastic, thanks for your support.

Creep age sounds criminal
